# Applescript for Outlook 2011 to iterate through all folders such as inbox etc

Tags: macos, applescript, outlook-2011

I want to loop throgh all the folders of outlook 2011 in MAC computer using Apple script (means just sort of automation).

i have script which throws error while running.

```
 tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
   set thisAccount to exchange account "Sigmaco"
   set thisFolders to mail folder of thisAccount
 end tell

 *tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to set folderList to the folders*

 repeat with nextFolder in folderList
    my ProcessFolder(nextFolder, outputFolder)
 end repeat
```

but the line in bold style throws error that it cannot iterate through all folders.

please help...

Answer (score 2):

because accounts can have the same name (assuming) you have to specify first one  then drill down like this

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    repeat with afolder in (mail folders of (first exchange account whose name is "Sigmaco"))
        log (get name of afolder)
    end repeat
end tell
```

if you want to iterate through all folders of all accounts you can skip a bit of the drilling

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    repeat with afolder in mail folders
    -- do stuff
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: it throws error :         "miscrosoft outlook got an error : can't get every folder." number -1728 from every folder

Comment: is it and exchange account, or imap or pop ? also is that the exact name

Comment: well its one of four types exchange, pop, imap, ldap see update to figure it out

Comment: Okie. you mean that i can try  1) ....(mail folders of (first exchange account ....      2) (mail folders of (first pop account        3) (mail folders of (first imap account   etc...

Comment: right then you'll know which one , I'm trying to put together a bit of code that can figure it out and proceed but you may just do that and move on :)

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to loop through the account types so you're just gonna to to use an if then else statement or know which type the account is